# Bootstrap tooltip image - position top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, position, tooltip

```
<div id="test"> <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Elef_Millim_-_Netanya_IMG_4251_05.jpg'/>" href="#">#testing</a>
 <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='http://engcomm.engin.umich.edu/campaign/img/big/chameleon-istock_large.jpg'/>" href="#">#testing</a>
 <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Elef_Millim_-_Netanya_IMG_4251_05.jpg'/>" href="#">#testing</a>
 <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='http://demo.athemes.com/flato/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2013/03/unicorn-wallpaper.jpg'/>" href="#">#testing</a>

</div>
```

---

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip({
    html: true,
    trigger: "hover",
    placement: "top"
});
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4WwQ/971/)

Opening tooltip have a strange effect.
Tooltip gets mad if necessarily wanted to start from the bottom position in the script where I have set to the TOP.

I tried with smaller images (max 200px) but it does not help.
The effect happens only at the newly loaded image.
It should clear the browser cache.
Look video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKlM-1xiQCQ

Comment: I can't replicate this issue.

Comment: you use mozilla or chrome ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but I tested on Mozilla and I still see no issue.

Comment: Maybe u have fast internet :P
Look this video - https://youtu.be/2qjqm2qJEqg (sorry for quality)

Comment: I replicate the issue when the img aren't loaded or are loading... (chrome /mac)

Comment: Please look - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKlM-1xiQCQ&
I try set min-height:200px for div .tooltip-inner

Fault css or my internet ?
Maybe my computer ? :P

btw. i have newest version google chrome. (win 7)

Please help me :(

Comment: My cousin has the same problem on chrome and mozilla : /
He have 20mb/s internet.